# What's the implication of the Frobenius automorphism to DLP

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, cryptography

Given a field, e.g. GF(p^x), does the existence of a Frobenius automorphism affect the difficulty of calculating the discrete log in that field?

How about other morphisms?

Comment: I'm not an expert on DLP, but I don't think there are any attacks using the Frobenius automorphism per se. OTOH the presence of non-trivial subfield (the case when $x$ is not a prime) does help in the sense that you can derive information using the norm map (an easily computable morphism) to the smaller field.

Comment: If taken literally including "other morphisms" to a bag of tricks would make the problem trivial. After all, the discrete logarithm itself is a group homomorphism from $(GF(p^x)^*,\cdot)$ to $(\Bbb{Z}_{p^x-1},+)$. I guess you mean "computable morphism".

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, I meant computable morphisms, thanks for pointing it out. You can assume the field has a number of small subfields and one large subfield of a large prime order.